# Java Trying to create a class to print ArrayList to File

Tags: java, class, serialization, file-io, printwriter

So I have an `ArrayList` of objects that I would like to print to file.  I have a `PrintToFile` class, and in another class I have an `ArrayList<Expenses> expList`

Here is my PrintToFile class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PrintToFile{
    public void PrintToFile()throws Exception{
      File f = new File ("Output.txt");
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
   }

    public void printExp(ArrayList<Expense> expList){
        for(int i = 0; i < expList.size(); i++){
         pw.println("---------------------------------------");//line 13
         pw.println(expList.get(i));
      }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

and here is my attempt to call to that class in my main class

```
    PrintToFile printer = new PrintToFile();
    printer.print(expList);
```

the first compiler error that I am getting is in my PrintToFile class, it says `PrintToFile.java:13: error: cannot find symbol`, which is the first call to `pw`

Im trying to figure out how to build and structure classes, so that not everything is just stuck in the main method of my main class.  So essentially I am trying to create a class that I can always call upon to print an ArrayList.

So my question is, how do I structure the `PrintToFile` class so that my `printExp` method can see the `PrintWriter` `pw` that I created.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why not save them as XML?  XML files are vaguely human readable as they come, and very readable using XSLT.  Turn the `Expense` class into a bean then look to `XMLDecoder` & `XMLEncoder` to read/write the entire `ArrayList<Expense>`.  Easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `pw` is a local variable in method `PrintToFile`, another method `printExp` cannot access it.

> Local Variables Similar to how an object stores its state in fields, a method will often store its temporary state in local variables. The syntax for declaring a local variable is similar to declaring a field (for example, int count = 0;). There is no special keyword designating a variable as local; that determination comes entirely from the location in which the variable is declared — which is **between the opening and closing braces of a method**. As such, **local variables are only visible to the methods in which they are declared; they are not accessible from the rest of the class.**

Please read about in the [Java Tutorial on Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `PrintWriter` as class variable then initialize it at your constructor. That's the reason why your method cannot find your variable `pw`.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `pw` in scope of `public void PrintToFile` method. It is invisible in the `public void printExp` method. Move the `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);` definition to the class level so it would be a member and then it will become visible to all class methods.

The below should do the magic:

```
 public class PrintToFile{
     private File f = new File ("Output.txt");
     private FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
     private PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);


    public void PrintToFile(String outFileAbsolutePath)throws Exception{
        this.f = new File (outFileAbsolutePath);
        this.fw = new FileWriter(this.f, true);
        this.pw = new PrintWriter(this.fw);
    }

    public void printExp(ArrayList<Expense> expList){
       for(int i = 0; i < expList.size(); i++){
         pw.println("---------------------------------------");//line 13
         pw.println(expList.get(i));
       }
       pw.close();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

the pw variable can't be accessed because it's declared inside a function and not available locally inside the class. You must do the following

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class PrintToFile{
         public PrintWriter pw; //<--declare it here

        public void PrintToFile()throws Exception{
          File f = new File ("Output.txt");
          FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
          pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
       }

        public void printExp(ArrayList<Expense> expList){
            for(int i = 0; i < expList.size(); i++){
             pw.println("---------------------------------------");//line 13
             pw.println(expList.get(i));
            }
            pw.close();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

pw must be a class level variable, currently the scope is inside method and it can not be accessed outside the method.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
    PrintWriter pw = null; // You need to declare it here
public class PrintToFile{
    public void PrintToFile()throws Exception{
      File f = new File ("Output.txt");
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
      pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
   }

    public void printExp(ArrayList<Expense> expList){
        for(int i = 0; i < expList.size(); i++){
              if(pw != null){ // need to check for null, as  it might be null
                  pw.println("---------------------------------------");//line 13
                  pw.println(expList.get(i));
              }

      }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Variables declared as method parameters can be accessed from within the method body. Class-level variables are accessible from anywhere in the class.

If a method declares a local variable that has the same name as a class-level variable, the former will 'shadow' the latter. To access the class-level variable from inside the method body, use the this keyword.

For more details on variable scope, you can see [this](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)